# How to list channels when the user is not a Content Owner

Tags: youtube-api

I am working for a client with hundreds of Youtube channels.
They cannot use Content Owner as it seems it is reserved to Youtube creators.

We are trying to use https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list, which has 4 signatures. 
There is a user X that has been added as a co-owner to all channels

- content owner is impossible to use, obviously
- We tried list (by YouTube username) by supplying a forUser parameter : it returns nothing when supplied X ==> how are we supposed to use that parameter ?
- We tried list (my channel)

  - the API requires 2 rounds of authentification
  - authenticating twice as X

    - returns only one channel (presumably the default channel for that user)
    - authenticating once as X, then choosing one of the channels underneath

      - returns all the channels for that brands (yay !)
      - the client doesn't know how to make this happen in a scripted way (today they manually click on the OAuth windows, get a tocken, do that for every brand, and then use a script that leverages the tocken. This sounds super broken, but I don't know how to help them.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you just want to  get the videos from those channels all you need is an API key and the channel IDs. No auth necessary.

Comment: I would like to get channel reports : https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/channel_reports , but I need to find a way to "discover" all the channels the analytics user has access to.